# Scrapy : restarting a scraping loop when it's finished from within the spider

Tags: python, scrapy

I am trying to figure out how to restart a scraping loop once it's over.

My logic is something like:

```
def start_requests():

    # get a list of coordinates from a database and the last page that got parsed on those coordinates

    for coordinate in coordinates:
        yield scrapy.Request(
            f"{settings.BASE_URL}/search.json?latitude={coordinate.latitude}&longitude={coordinate.longitude}&page={coordinate.current_page}",
            callback = self.parse_coordinates,
            cb_kwargs={'coordinate': coordinate}
        )

def parse_coordinates(self, response, coordinate):
    # parse the page
    # and identify if I reach the last page
    if not last_page: 
        # update coordinate so the scrapy.Request will parse the next page 
        yield scrapy.Request(
            f"{settings.BASE_URL}/search.json?latitude={coordinate.latitude}&longitude={coordinate.longitude}&page={coordinate.current_page}",
            callback = self.parse_coordinates,
            cb_kwargs={'coordinate': coordinate}
            )
    else:
        # reset the page counter to 1 so next time I run the loop I start over
```

In the end what happens is that I have many coordinates, out of which I'll scrape many pages.

Once this ends, I would like to wait a certain amount of time and reset the loop (i.e. calling again start_requests()). The reset should be performed directly within the spider. The only alternative would be using scrapyd (which I do not know yet) as ultimately I will manage & monitor my jobs using it.

Until now I can't find how to do it. I tried :

1. Pause the code at the end of start_requests, but it pauses the whole thread, so I do not scrape anything
2. Uses a recurrent task (task.LoopingCall(self.control_loop)) the same way the Logstats extension is working, but as soon as the main loop finishes, it closes the spider

What would be the correct approach ?

Comment: Is it OK with you to wait for the spider to finish, and then to run it again?

Comment: I run the spider manualy (> scrapy crawl spidername) and ultimately I'll have it managed by scrapyd. Dunno much the library yet (scrapyd), so maybe it has some built in functionality of the sort, but I would prefer to deal with it from the spider. I was gonna explore the spider `close()` method, didn't had time yet. Is that what you meant ?  Or is it through some independent python script that'll manage the loop of running the spider ?

Comment: I meant the latter.

Comment: So no I won't use that option, I'll update the title / content so it's clearer